# Samba unbuntu 22.04 share something that is not in /home

Tags: samba

Here's my problem; if i set `path = /home/user/share/` inside of `/etc/samba/smb.conf` i can then type in `smb://192.168.0.xxx/share/` and connect with a user and password or as a guest depending on the settings.

The problem is i cannot place the desired ZFS pool i wish to share in this location.

Well, that's not entirely true i can mount it in this location and get the sharing to work, but then i can't get my plex media server to access the files properly.

So i thought i could just mount my pool in `/mnt/` and share it from there, unfortunately samba has something built in to point it directly to this home folder.

If i set `path = /mnt/share/` inside of `/etc/samba/smb.conf` there is no way to connect to it as using `smb://192.168.0.xxx/share/` as this is actually trying to share the folder in the location `/home/user/share/` which isn't where the pool is located, so it just gives an error saying nothing there to share.

Is there some way to force samba to connect to where the shared folder actually is, even its not in the /home/user/ directory?

If not is there a diffrent way i can share without using samba; perhaps using ZFS?

EDITL

Somehow i managed to get this working in diffrent ways for my windows boxs vs linux ones, by using a pool share of my zfs for linux boxes and by adding a hard drive location for the windows boxes inside of the `/etc/samba/smb.conf` then just connecting to `\\servername\HardDrive`